# Flutter Dynamic maxHeight

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I build a scrolling textfield like proposed in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9365. Now I want the maxHeight of the ConstrainedBox change dynamically, according to the shown or not shown keyboard. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
Widget _buildTextInput() {
 return new Container(
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
  child: new ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: new BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: 150.0 <-- This should be dynamic
    ),

    child: new SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      reverse: true,

      // here's the actual text box
      child: new TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null, //grow automatically
        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: 'Please enter a lot of text',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

[The red box should be the constrained box with open keyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJBNd.png)

[And like so with a closed keyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH0KO.png)

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to build an input field that's kind of like posting on Twitter. I need to combine a CircleAvatar, a TextField and a GridView to display the user's avatar, his post and a few images. Like on Twitter, I want the whole thing to scroll, not only the TextField - both while typing and while reviewing what the user typed or uploaded. Besides, the (multiline) TextField should scroll while typing in the visible area (keeping the open or closed keyboard in mind), so the user can see what he's typing.

Even though the Flutter TextField autoscrolls now, I can't get this whole cluster working. Any idea?

Comment: I do not see a problem with making it dynamic. You can easily fit this into a `StatefulWidget` and update the value, or do you have problems detecting the keyboard?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I don't have a clue how to calculate the remaining space. And how to detect, when the keyboard is opened. :)

Comment: You can replace the `ConstraintBox` by an `Expanded` widget, wich will take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscroll has been supported natively in the textfield widget since I believe the beginning of June (2018) - I think [this is the commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/2ab60e93ef2bf3cd6fa32f76bb8ba296225dd7b8) that added it. You may need to update to the most recent flutter build for it to work, but that is included in version 5.5.

This simplifies matters a bit - this should be all you need to do to get it to work as you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Example"),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
          child: new TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: null,
            decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
              hintText: 'Please enter a lot of text',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: To answer the OP's edited question - wanting to have other elements within the same scrolling pane as the textview, I've made this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Example"),
        ),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  child: new Text("AB"),
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Column(
                    children: [
                      new TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        maxLines: null,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                          hintText: 'Please enter a lot of text',
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        height: 300.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

By using a SingleChildScrollView, we're still allowing the children to set the size of the viewport (as opposed to a MultiChildLayoutDelegate etc which has to have that size set). The textview grows as big as it needs to be, but doesn't scroll itself as its height is not constrained. The `Expanded` is needed within the row to make sure that the right side (with the text & pictures) is as large as it can be horizontally.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. But the outcome of this is yet another question. :) Is there a way to put a container in the same "scrollview" the textfield produces when being bigger than "possible"?

Comment: Because as soon as I put the textfield into a ListView it stops autoscrolling. (Expanded -> ListView -> [Container, TextField]). This is kinda tricky.

Comment: Ah. I was interpreting your comment differently. So the reason that is happening is because ListView itself is scrollable, so the textview can simply expand to as big as it needs to be within that listview. Instead of the textview itself scrolling, the entire listview will scroll.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve so I don't know how that behaviour differs. It might be worth asking another question and explaning what you're trying to achieve (possibly with pictures or a hand-drawn diagram if possible) as comments aren't really meant for extended discussion. If you could link it to it from here I'll take a look though =). Or you could edit this question with a clarification, although it is useful as-is.

Comment: Yeah, at first I thought it was the answers I was looking for, but I realized a bit later it wasn't, unfortunately. So I guess I need to implement my first idea (origin post), where I put the textfield in a constrained box that is as high as the space between the appbar and the keyboard (or appbar and bottom bar)? Is there a way to calculate this?

Comment: I still think there's a better way than a manual calculation which will be fairly difficult and not really ideal. There should be some combination of Container + ListView or Column + Expanded?  + TextField that does what you need - could you maybe explain what you want your end result to be rather than how you think you should do it? And you could do that in an edit to your original question if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I edited my original post. :)

Comment: @aksn I've updated my answer with a solution to your edited question. Hopefully it does what you need =)